# AssertionError: <bound method comment.created_at of <solution.comment object at 0x7f3db6beba58>> is not an instance of <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Tags: python-3.x

## I am new to python and am trying to learn OOP. I have this mock up quiz that i have been trying to solve. So far am able to pass 5 test

### Here is the challenge

Users come in 3 flavors, normal users, moderators, and admins. Normal users can only create new comments, and edit the their own comments. Moderators have the added ability to delete comments (to remove trolls), while admins have the ability to edit or delete any comment.
Users can log in and out, and we track when they last logged in
Comments

Encapsulation of Properties

All classes should have no publicly accessible fields
You should make sure you at least "hide" the required fields, for example, using _name instead of _name. Alternatively, feel free to use a better solution as extra credit.
The method-based API is provided. These must be completed as-is.
Additional methods are allowed, though remember to keep read-only properties read-only.
Instantiation

Classes should be instantiated with properties (as provided), to create instances with values already assigned.
User/Moderator/Admin defaults:
Should be marked as not logged in
Should return None for the last logged in at property
Comment defaults:
Should set the current timestamp for the created at property upon instantiation
Replied To is optional, and should be None if not provided.
Inheritance & Access Control

User
Users can be logged in and out.
When logging in, set the last_logged_in_at timestamp. Do not modify this timestamp when logging out
Users can only edit their own comments
Users cannot delete any comments
Moderator is a User
Moderators can only edit their own comments
Moderators can delete any comments
Admin is both a User and a Moderator
Admins can edit any comments
Admins can delete any comments
Composition

Comments contain a reference to the User who created it (author)
Comments optionally contain a reference to another comment (replied_to)
When converting to a string (to_string), the following format is used:
No replied to:
message + " by " + author.name
With replied to:
message + " by " + author.name + " (replied to " + repliedTo.author.name + ")"

### this is my solution

```
import datetime
class user:

  def __init__(self, name, lastloggedIn = None):
    self.name = name
    self.loggedIn = False
    self.lastloggedIn = None

  def name(self):
    return self.name

  def name(self, value):
    self.name = value    

  def is_logged_in(self):
    return self.loggedIn

  def last_logged_in_at(self):
    return self.lastloggedIn

  def log_in(self):
    self.loggedIn = True
    self.lastloggedIn = datetime.datetime.utcnow()


  def log_out(self):
    self.loggedIn = False

  def can_edit(self, comment):
    if comment.author.name == self.name:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def can_delete(self, comment):
    return False

#   def to_string(self):
#       pass

class moderator(user):
  def __init__(self, name):
    user.__init__(self, name)

  def can_delete(self, comment):
    return True



class admin(moderator):

  def __init__(self, name):
    moderator.__init__(self, name)

  def can_edit(self, comment):
    return True    


class comment:
  def __init__(self, author, message, replied_to = None, createdAt = None):
    self.createdAt = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.author = author
    self.message = message
    self.replied_to = replied_to

  def author(self):
    return self._author

  def author(self, value):
    self.author = value

  def message(self):
    return self.message

  def message(self, value):
      self.message = value

  def created_at(self):
      return self.createdAt

  def replied_to(self):
      return self.replied_to

  def replied_to(self, value):
      self.replied_to = value

  def to_string(self):
      if self.replied_to == None:
          return self.replied_to + " by " + self.author.name




import unittest

user1 = user('User 1')
mod = moderator('Moderator')

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_instantiation(self):
    self.assertEqual(user1.name,'User 1', 'User name is set correctly')
    user1.name = 'User 1 Updated'
    self.assertEqual(user1.name,'User 1 Updated', 'User name can be updated')
    self.assertIsInstance(mod, user, 'Moderator is a user')
```

### Am getting two main errors. the last_logged_in method should return None and the datetime.datetime.now() doesn't seem to be working correctly

```
AssertionError: <bound method comment.created_at of <solution.comment object at 0x7fd5a21d0668>> is not an instance of <class 'datetime.datetime'>

AssertionError: <bound method user.last_logged_in_at of <[35 chars]ba8>> != None : Last logged in date is not set by default
```

Comment: Your question is way too long for SO. Should you read [mcve] before asking. Please, edit your question.

Comment: `self.assertIsInstance(mod, user, 'Moderator is a user')` The third argument is a message that is displayed when the assertion _fails_.  You've got it backwards -- it should be `Moderator is not a user`.

Comment: Your code cannot be [tag:python-3.x] and [tag:python-2.7] at the same time. Please remove one of the tags.

Comment: @Rarblack ,  thank you.  Am working on that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the errors you're getting from your unit tests, but I do see some obvious issues in your code. To start with, you're very often using the same name for instance variables and for methods at the same time. That is very unlikely to work as you want it to. You're also defining multiple methods with different signatures, but the same name. That kind of name overloading is allowed in some other languages (like C++), but it doesn't work as you probably intend it to in Python.

Comment: @Blckknght - Am getting two main errors. the last_logged_in method should return None and the datetime.datetime.now() doesn't seem to be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first error:

```
AssertionError: <bound method comment.created_at of <solution.comment object at 0x7fd5a21d0668>> is not an instance of <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

ITsays you are passing **datetime instance**. Let's check:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 21, 10, 28, 26, 996940) # this is datetime instance
```

what you can do is convert it to ***string*** and pass it:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2018-11-21 06:51:22'
```

Like:

```
class comment:
  def __init__(self, author, message, replied_to = None, createdAt = None):
    self.createdAt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

For the second error:

```
AssertionError: <bound method user.last_logged_in_at of <[35 chars]ba8>> != None : Last logged in date is not set by default
```

You are not setting ***lastloggedIn***:

```
 def __init__(self, name, lastloggedIn = None):
    self.name = name
    self.loggedIn = False
    self.lastloggedIn = lastloggedIn
```

and same here you are passing an instance:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 21, 6, 46, 25, 248409)
```

change it to return the string instead of an instance:

```
 def log_in(self):
    self.loggedIn = True
    self.lastloggedIn = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```